# PHPMailer safe practices - Send escaped / sanitized variables or not?

Tags: php, variables, escaping, phpmailer

I'm using the PHPMailer-Lite class to build an email sending script and I'm not sure if I should use **addslashses()** on the **$name** variable when adding it to the constructor.

If somebody's last name would be *O'Riley* (or any other name that contains characters which should normally be sanitized before handling) and I would send it unescaped, wouldn't it mess with the script/email sending ? Is it safe to send it unescaped ? As a side note, I would also like to avoid having my message body say *"Hello, O\'Riley"*.

Looking at the source, I saw that it only trims the whitespace and line ending (\r\n) characters from the received $name variable, so any advice on this would be more than welcome.

Thank you all in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, PHPMailer handles that automatically.

If you pass it "Seamus O'Malley" it is properly formatted for sending in email.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Do you know if this applies to PHPMailer-Lite as well or do I have to switch to the normal version of PHPMailer ?

Comment: Looking at PHPMailer-Lite, looks like it will handle it as well.  You shouldn't need to switch.